# Asp.Net Report Failure. Why?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, reporting-services

I have set of reports on report server. One report '**Receipt**' is set to open right away after an operation (After Save) and another report '**Reprint**' would be opened upon users choice. this report would be a receipt. This report is made from SSRS.

My problem is that I am getting this reports perfectly fine. Reports are working perfect but when I try to export an Receipt Report I get an error saying

> the source of the report definition has not been specified

so after that I opened this receipt from reprint report it exports perfectly.
**Could anyone please tell me why & how could I resolve it?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the report definition explicitly in your C# code.

```
   reportViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = reportPath
```

If the report uses an embedded resource try

```
   LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "path to rdlc.rdlc"
```

This commonly occurs when the report is in a separate referenced assembly.